# How to hide origin server behind CloudFlare and still send emails

Tags: email, proxy, smtp, ip, cloudflare

How do you hide an origin server behind CloudFlare and still be able to send transactional emails via providers like Sendgrid, Mailgun, etc.?

My problem is that when I send an email it seems that a `Received: from` line is always added to the message, revealing my origin server's real IP.

I tried it with Sendgrid, both via JSON API and SMTP endpoints, but it's visible in both cases.

How do you solve this problem?

1. Are there some transactional email providers which do not append this line?
2. Do you use some complicated setup with a distributed message queue and a worker running on a different host with different IP, only for sending emails?
3. Do you connect to the providers via a proxy / VPN? Is there such a thing as proxy for SMTP?

Answer (score 0):

In your case we recommend running your email through a different server.  You can find some guidance in this [KB article](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170166-General-website-security-guidelines).  If your IP is still leaked you should contact Cloudflare support.

> Run email on separate server/service If you are running your mail on
>   the same server as your website, then the attacker can always find
>   your origin server IP. To close this possible security gap, you can
>   use an email service on a separate server than your website, whether
>   through your hosting provider or an outside service (e.g., Google
>   Apps).
>
> For Mac users:
>
> You can run this command in Terminal to see what IP is being reported
>   with your MX records:
>
> dig +short $(dig mx +short WEBSITE) For example, if I was concerned
>   about example.com, I would enter:
>
> dig +short $(dig mx +short example.com) The output will be an IP
>   address. This is the IP address that an attacker can always find. You
>   want to make sure this IP address is different that the IP address for
>   your web server. Otherwise, no matter how many times you change your
>   web server, if your email is also on the same server, then the
>   attacker can always find the new IP.
>
> For PC users:
>
> You can run this command in command prompt to see what IP is being
>   reported with your MX records:
>
> nslookup -q=mx WEBSITE For example, if I was concerned about
>   example.com, I would enter:
>
> nslookup -q=mx example.com The output will be an IP address. This is
>   the IP address that an attacker can always find. You want to make sure
>   this IP address is different that the IP address for your web server.
>   Otherwise, no matter how many times you change your web server, if
>   your email is also on the same server, then the attacker can always
>   find the new IP.